# how to add dropdown menu in IBM Watson Chatbot

Tags: websphere, dropdown, watson-assistant

I am using IBM Watson Chatbot for showing drop down menu so user can select the option what ever they want by clicking the option. please guide me in this regard..

Comment: In what client do you want to use that? Have you tested the "option" response in Watson Assistant? Please add more details. And why is it tagged "websphere" and not "ibm-cloud"?

Comment: i don't know how to go to "options" response and i couldn't find it. I'm basically trying to present options to my user so he could choose one from them but I'm really lost. Also ignore the tag, this is the first time i have used stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, open the JSON editor for the response, and then add a `preference` name and value pair before the response_type name and value pair. You can set the preference to `dropdown` or `button`.

[image: Click here]

Example:

```
    {
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "title": "Insurance types",
        "options": [
          {
            "label": "Boat",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "I want to buy boat insurance."
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Car",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "I want to buy car insurance."
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "House",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "I want to buy house insurance."
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "preference": "dropdown", //add this name and value pair 
        "description": "Which of these items do you want to insure?",
        "response_type": "option"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: When you define an options list with only 3 items, the options are typically displayed as buttons. When you add a preference property that indicates dropdown as the preference.